# In the show, it isn't very clear but in the books where do the dragon eggs come from?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know Jorah gives them to Daenerys, but where did he get them from?
Why are there no more Dragons?

Comment: You've asked two very different questions. I recommend you remove the second as you question may be closed for being too broad

Comment: Jorah did not give them to her. Also, dupe alert.